# HPA with External metric sending to the wrong namespace

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, autoscaling

I'm brand new to Kubernetes and apologies if this is extremely basic.

I'm trying to scale a Kafka consumer based on the Kafka lag. I have the metric in Prometheus and, based on https://medium.com/@roman.noze/kubernetes-pods-autoscaling-with-kafka-metrics-9b7d5ec3c1d3) set up a Prometheus Adapter to be:

```
externalRules:
  - metricsQuery: sum(min_over_time(kafka_consumergroup_lag{<< range $key, $value :=.LabelValuesByName >><< if ne $key "namespace" >><< $key >>="<< $value >>",<<end >><< end >>}[1h])) by (topic,consumergroup)
    name:
      as: kafka_lag
    resources:
      template: <<.Resource>>
    seriesQuery: '{topic!="",__name__=~"kafka_consumergroup_lag"}'
```

This is deployed in the `monitoring` namespace. Subsequently I have my HPA set up in the `default` namespace to be:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: kafka-consumer
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: kafka-consumer
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
    - type: External
      external:
        metric:
          name: kafka_lag
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              namespace: monitoring
              topic: test_topic
        target:
          type: Value
          value: "20"
```

However, when I run this I see in the Prometheus Adapter logs I see

```
URI="/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/kafka_lag?labelSelector=namespace%3Dmonitoring%2Ctopic%3Dtest_topic" latency="8.162946ms" userAgent="kube-controller-manager/v1.27.4 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/3d90c09/system:serviceaccount:kube-system:horizontal-pod-autoscaler" audit-ID="5c45a9bb-fa7b-43c6-b329-8e3b302a4762" srcIP="10.10.9.215:38530" resp=404
```

Why is this going to the `/namespaces/default` endpoint and how do I redirect it? I tried setting `namespaced: false` and using the `annotations` as per https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/blob/master/docs/externalmetrics.md but that didn't do anything.

Anyone have success setting this up?